# I need to design one popup where i can display the data half on the left and half on the right side,

Tags: javascript, html

I have 100 rows, I need to display in a popup. So, 50 rows should be displayed in left side of the popup and 50 rows should be displayed right side of the popup.

This is my HTML code that I have tried. But, I can not get two tables.

HTML Code

```
<div class="panel-body p0">
  <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="itemListArray" style=" list-style: none outside none;  padding-inline-start: 15px; ">
    <li class="featureContentBox-30" ng-style="{ 'cursor' : (sortableEventStart == true) ? 'all-scroll' : 'default' }" ng-repeat="dimension in (itemListArray | limitTo: totalShow.count) track by $index">
      <div class="row p10">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          {{$index+1}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          {{dimension.valueName}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">{{dimension.displayName}} </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1" ng-click="removeDimension($index)"> x</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think in this way...

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-6">
  // left side
 </div>
 <div class="col-6">
  // right side
 </div>
</div>
```